# How do I use Next.js 13 with NPM workspaces?

Tags: npm, next.js, monorepo, npm-workspaces

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "mysterian",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/common",
    "packages/webapp"
  ]
}
```

In `packages/webapp/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`, I have:

```
import { FirestoreService } from "common/firestore";
```

My `packages/common/index.ts` has

```
export * from './firestore';
```

and `packages/common/firestore.ts` has:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import { resolve, join } from 'path';
import { DataSource, Document } from 'common/types/db';

const absolutePath = resolve(join(__dirname, 'credentials', 'firebase_service_credentials.json'));
console.log({ absolutePath })
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(require(absolutePath))
});
```

my `absolutePath` however has: `../packages/webapp/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/credentials/firebase_service_credentials.json'`

Where it doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?